# User Activity Tracking - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I would like to track the below activities of my users in my website

For each user’s visit into the website

1. When they log in and log off (date & time)
2. What files they downloaded …along with who and when
3. What webpages they looked at

Is it possible using Google Analytics? I hear that google Universal analytics has a userId feature. Is it possible with Universal Analytics?

Comment: Not sure if you are using classic or universal analytics but check out events.

Comment: To be able to tie in all those activities and events (log on/off, downloads, pages viewed) to specific users, you would likely need the User ID feature. Not sure if you could pinpoint times though.